# Causing an area hidden by CSS to fade in through Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello and thanks in advance for any thoughts. I have some code that I was using on one squarespace site and it works perfectly. After a few seconds, a hidden DIV fades in. However I'm trying to use it on another squarespace site and it's just not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('div.hidden').fadeIn(3000).removeClass('hidden');
  }, 5000);
});
```

```css
div.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<div class="hidden">
  any content I want in here
</div>
```

Like I mentioned before, it works perfectly on one site but when I copy and paste it into another site, nothing happens. The content is hidden, so I assume the CSS works, but nothing is revealed after a few seconds. I wonder if there was some quirk about the other site that makes it work that I'm missing here?

I'm not huge on javascript so please be gentle. Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: The code appears to be working correctly. The issue must be with some other aspect of the page/code. Check your developer's console for errors.By the way, the use of `.fadeIn()` is all you need. `.removeClass()` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Thank you to Scott Marcus for the suggestion to check for errors (duh, I should've thought of that). I needed a "S" in the HTTP: calling for the latest jquery. It wanted https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js not http://

THANK YOU. Saved my bacon!